# sed remove first two characters if some string existed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following file.txt:

```
b.howareyou
hello
goodbye
b.hello
howareyou
b.goodbye
b.test
testb.
testb.test
```

I want the following output:

```
howareyou
hello
goodbye
hello
howareyou
goodbye
test
testb.
testb.test
```

I want check if **first two characters**  are `b.` then remove that two characters.

I have tried some solutions without satisfactory result.

Comment: `the remove remove that two characters` ?

Comment: no problem. I suggested an edit for you, but was rejected by some indian moderator *anger*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use sed like below,

```
sed 's/^b\.//' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `b` Matches a literal `b`
- `\.` Matches a literal dot.
- Replacing the matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`Awk` solution can be like

```
$ awk -F. '/^b./{$0=$2} 1' input
howareyou
hello
goodbye
hello
howareyou
goodbye
test
testb.
testb.test
```

**What it does?**

- `-F.` sets the field seperator as `.`
- `'/^b./{$0=$2}` if the line starts with `b.`, sets the record `$0` as `$2` which follows the `.`
- `1` true for every line, takes the default action to print the entire record, `$0`

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F '^b\.' '{print $1$2}' file
howareyou
hello
goodbye
hello
howareyou
goodbye
test
testb.
testb.test
```

- This awk is using field separator as `^b\.` which means b followed by dot only at line start.
- Lines that start with `b.` will have rest of line in `$2` and lines that don't have `b.` at the start will have full line in `$1`. So either of `$1` and `$2` will be empty hence `print`$1$2`prints the correct output i.e. line without`b.` at starting.